# CK Editor strange characters

Tags: ckeditor

I have just installed CK Editor onto a form that submits data to a database, when I want to use an apostrophe ' It is displaying as & #39; on my web page instead.

How can I get it to display an apostrophe instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that somewhere along the line, CKEditor (or maybe another part of the system) is going through and converting characters that might potentially cause problems (due to having special meaning in HTML) into their [HTML entity representations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

This is normal behaviour and if you don't need to do any string manipulation inside your database you can happily leave it as is for that stage. Indeed you can have them in along with normal HTML text and it should render just fine.

Clearly your setup is sufficiently different that something isn't happening. So, you'll want to use something like [PHP's `html_entity_decode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to convert back to normal unescaped text. There should be an equivalent function available in any language with a half-decent standard library.

Comment: Thank you, it appears I was replacing "&" characters with "&amp;" I have changed this to single out any solitary " & " Hence I was getting &amp;#39; which obviously wasn't decoding correctly. Thank you for your help